# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) on project XYZ(Project name): Mark invalid

Tags: maven

When I try to execute mvn clean install, I faced with this error and It was working properly until now. Is there any one who can help me?

Comment: Please add the full log output to the post...furthermore which version of Maven, Java, etc. you are using? Are you using it on plain command line or from within an IDE? and very important your full pom file...

Comment: I use it in IDE, the maven version that I used is 3.0.3, Java is 1.8.